# problem in writing data and matrix elements into text file

Tags: matlab, matrix, file-io

I have a problem with writing data to a file in Matlab, I have an LP problem that their solution is a vector of size n, and I want to write some information about this solution in a text file to read it any time I want,
(I don not want to save workspace in matlab)
I write the following code

```
n = 5;
Length = 10;
s = [1;0;1;0];
t = 0.6;
Test = fopen('Test.txt', 'w');
fprintf(Test,'TSP Problem Size is: %d \n', n);
fprintf(Test,'Optimal Length is: %.5f \n', Length);
fprintf(Test,'Time To Solve in seconds is: %f \n', t);
fprintf(Test,'Solution is: \n');
for i=1:size(s) 
   fprintf(Test,'%.0f\n', s(i));
end
fclose(Test);
```

and when I execute 'type(Test.txt);'  it appears as I want
but when I open file in windows explorer it appears all as one line, I don't know why ???
is there any way to keep formatting  and to write the solution every value in a separate line
(I try dlmwrite but it writes only matrix, I need to write some information then the matrix)

thank you for your help

Comment: Are you using Windows OS?

Comment: I am sorry to late but I think nobody interact with this quetion, yes I am using windows 7 64-bit

Comment: Please use `\r\n` for new line in Windows. For details, please read the answers in the marked duplicate question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between \n and \r?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r)